# Access a string as an array, check the value of an index and perhaps change the character in that index

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have been trying to read a string and then one by one for each character run a random number if a 5 is generated then change the character from a 1 to a 0 or vice versa. I feel I am almost there this is my thirds attempt at this, but I have a slight problem with writing to the index, as it tells me it is read only. Here is my code:

```
string mutate = "1010";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int MutProbablity = random.Next(1, 1000);
    if (MutProbablity == 5)
    {
        if (mutate[i] == '0')
        {
            mutate[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (mutate[i] == '1')
        {
            mutate[i] = '0';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my error:

> Property or indexer '`string.this[int]`' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Can someone tell me how I can get around this issue or perhaps suggest a different way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable, so you won't be able to modify any characters, but you can accomplish your goal by first converting it to a `char[]`, which is mutable.

Like this:

```
var chars = mutate.ToCharArray();     // convert to char[]
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int MutProbablity = random.Next(1, 1000);
    if (MutProbablity == 5)
    {
        if (chars[i] == '0')
        {
            chars[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (chars[i] == '1')
        {
            chars[i] = '0';
        }
    }
}

mutate = new String(chars);    // convert to back to string
```

Another way to do this would be to use Linq (and an admittedly *very* ugly string of ternary operators).

```
var new string(mutate.Select(c => 
    (random.Next(1, 1000) == 5) ? ((c == '0') ? '1' : (c == '1') ? '0' : c) : c).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to try this now, I was sure I tried something similar to this but I must have done it wrong! I will let you know how I get on! :)

Comment: The second method looks confusing! :) I have never used Linq before I have heard of it though. Cheers!

Comment: @deucalion0 It's just a much more compact way of doing the same thing. I actually wouldn't recommended it for production code just because it's difficult to read, but I wanted to include it just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks for this it works of course, and I now know how to work with characters and strings, so thanks!!! AN thanks for the completeness too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

It provides a single char change, and much more useful methods

Answer (score 1):

Is your `mutate` string just composed of 0 and 1?
The StringBuilder could be used to change a single char inside the string

```
Random r = new Random();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("0101");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int MutProbablity = r.Next(1, 1000);
    if (MutProbablity == 5)
    {
        b[i] = (b[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, strings are immutable, but the class `StringBuilder` is really a mutable string. Create a custom class using a StringBuilder as the backing store, something along these lines:

```
class MyMutableString
{
  private StringBuilder backingStore ;
  private string        currentValue ;
  public MyMutableString()
  {
    this.backingStore = new StringBuilder() ;
    this.currentValue = this.backingStore.ToString() ;
    return ;
  }
  public MyMutableString( string initialValue )
  {
    this.backingStore = new StringBuilder( initialValue ) ;
    this.currentValue = this.backingStore.ToString() ;
  }

  public string Value
  {
    get
    {
        return this.currentValue ;
    }
    set
    {
      this.backingStore.Length = 0 ;
      this.backingStore.Append( value ) ;
      this.currentValue = this.backingStore.ToString() ;
    }
  }

  public void Mutate( int mutationThreshold , Dictionary<char,char> mutations )
  {
    int probability = GetNextRandomValue() ;
    if ( probability == mutationThreshold )
    {
      int replacementsMade = 0 ;
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.backingStore.Length ; ++i )
      {
        char c = this.backingStore[i] ;
        char r ;
        bool mutate = mutations.TryGetValue(c, out r ) ;
        if ( mutate )
        {
           this.backingStore[i] = r ;
           ++replacementsMade ;
        }
      }
      this.currentValue = this.backingStore.ToString() ;
    }
    return ;
  }

  private static readonly Random random = new Random() ;
  private int GetNextRandomValue()
  {
    int value = random.Next(1,1000) ;
    return value ;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will save this code in my toolbox! :) Much appreciated!